# I want fullCalendar agendarWeek timezone mouse over event but I do not know how to use it

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I want fullCalendar agendarWeek timezone mouse over event but I do not know how to use it.

I tried this:

```
$('td.fc-widget-content').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).append("hi");
});
```

So the all-day part works, but the time part. There is a problem that only one line is entered because there is only one td.

I want when mouse over time td  show custom emoticon

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with CSS, there is no need for js in this case:

```
td.fc-widget-content {
   cursor: url(/path/to/file.png), auto;
}
```